# Crash loading data from coreData in airplane mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

When I load my app with internet then go into airplane mode I can load posts saved to the coreData fine. But If I load my airplane already in airplane mode I get a crash on this line:

```
let results = try moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

from this function:

```
   func loadImages(_ fetched:@escaping (_ images:[FullRes]?) -> Void) {

    saveQueue.async() {
        let context = self.getContext()

        guard let moc = context else {
            return
        }


        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = FullRes.fetchRequest()
        //let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = FullRes.fetchRequest()
        //let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "FullRes")//NSFetchRequest(entityName: "FullRes")


        do {

            let results = try moc.fetch(fetchRequest)

            let imageData = results as? [FullRes]
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                fetched(imageData)

            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

**And it gives me this message:**

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error:  is not a valid NSFetchRequest.'

Not sure why this is occuring...Any ideas?

Comment: If the error is about the request being invalid,  you need to include the source for `FullRes.fetchRequest()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by putting this

```
if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
    }
```

around my loadPosts() function in ViewDidload as it was calling methods from AppDelegate!

Took me hours ;)

Comment: That might stop your crash but it doesn't answer your question. From what you've said here, there's no reason that the network connection would affect your ability to use Core Data. You've hidden the problem but you haven't fixed it.

Comment: @TomHarrington Thanks for showing interest in this. Basically what was causing the problem was in the appDelegate I had setup setNetworkActivityIndicator & another function for showing a custom UIView on the Main View(for errors or internet connect etc). In the main view where I have the CoreData setup in the loadPosts function I was accessing those and using those two functions from the AppDelegate. when I removed those(deleted them from AppDelegate and removed the code for accessing them in the Main View) the CoreData was working again...

Comment: Now yes I have basically found a temporary solution for fixing this, but not sure what else I could do...Please let me know your thoughts.